# duplicate content penalties for cross posting?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have a blog ([xyious.blogspot.com](http://xyious.blogspot.com)) and a website ([xyious.com](http://xyious.com)), i'm developing a tiny cms system for my website while posting some content. I always post the new content to my blog as well as the website for several reasons.

Now i'm wondering how badly i will be penalized for duplicate content. The website is older than the blog, but never had a whole lot of content, and i obviously want my website to rank higher than the blog in the future when i stop posting on the blog in favor of having a website hosting all the content.

Do i incur duplicate content penalty, and if so how severe ? Would it be better to stop posting to the blog altogether before the cms is in a state where it displays content correctly and has easy navigation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the same content is found in more then one place it is duplicate content. If you must publish the content to both websites then block the blog from being crawled by Google or use canonical URLs with the main website being the primary URL. If the primary website is working as you would expect it to then there probably is no need to continue publishing to it. If possible redirect the old URLs to the new ones this was everyone, including Google, knows the new website is where this content will now permanently reside and to use it in the search results. It also transfers over your incoming links to the new site as well.